# Multiple response in action on google dialogflow

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

How can i get multiple response on action on google console using dialogflow ? 
i simulated on Action on google console but only two responses are showing on it 
where as third response are not showing

here is my json response

```
{
    "source": "webhook", 
    "data": {
        "google": {
            "is_ssml": true, 
            "permissions_request": null, 
            "expect_user_response": true
        }
    }, 
    "messages": [
        {
            "type": 0, 
            "speech": "peter Got around 28 marks in maths. which is ranked 1 among 3 candidate in class 1"
        }, 
        {
            "textToSpeech": "peter Got around 28 marks in maths. which is ranked 1 among 3 candidate in class 1", 
            "platform": "google", 
            "displayText": "peter Got around 28 marks in maths. which is ranked 1 among 3 candidate in class 1", 
            "type": "simple_response"
        }, 
        {
            "textToSpeech": "Working", 
            "platform": "google", 
            "displayText": "Working", 
            "type": "simple_response"
        }, 
        {
            "textToSpeech": "Working 2", 
            "platform": "google", 
            "displayText": "Working 2", 
            "type": "simple_response"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my console output

[image]

any help regarding this is much appreciated

Thank you

Regards Saif

Answer (score 0):

Only two simple responses will be accepted as a response. If you want more content you will need to consolidate your text into one of the two responses.

Comment: Thanks for the reply can you tell me how can i format the text  such as new line and bold

Comment: For simple responses, you should be able to add line break characters (/n). Rich formatting such as bold are only available for cards and other GUI.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on the [AoG Responses docs](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#simple_responses), it is specified as a requirement :

> At most 2 chat bubbles per turn

So your third bubble won't display, as intended by Google.

As suggested in the previous answer from Nick, you need to consolidate your text and wrap everything in your 2 bubbles. In a simple response, you can line break by adding a `\n` where needed.

In a [Basic Card](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#basic_card) however, you can access a limited subset of markdown, as stated in the docs link I provided, like that :

> `New line with a double space`
>
> `**bold**`
>
> `*italics*`

Answer (score 0):

**Rich responses** have the following requirements and optional properties that you can configure:

1. Supported on surfaces with the actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT
   capability.
2. The first item in a rich response must be a simple response.
3. At most two simple responses.
4. At most one basic card or StructuredResponse.
5. At most 8 suggestion chips. (you can add more than 8 also but you will get a warning not an error.)
6. Suggestion chips are not allowed in a FinalResponse
7. Linking out to the web from smart displays is currently not
   supported.